# Передача в конструктор std::thread шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Помогите разобраться в логике компилятора. Почему возникают данные ошибки? Так же прошу подсказать, как передавать шаблонные функции в поток.

Вызываемый пользователем метод `void GenSeqByte(T&& stream, size_t byte)`. Где `stream` универсальная ссылка на абстрактный поток/контейнер/..., для которого определена функция `write(T stream, const char *mem, size_t count)`.

```
template<typename T>
void GenSeqByte(T&& stream, size_t byte)
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(GenAndWriteSeq, std::ref(stream), std::ref(byte), std::ref(mtx)));
    }

    for (auto &t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Код функции `void GenAndWriteSeq(T&& stream, size_t &bytes, std::mutex &m)`.

```
template<typename T>
void GenAndWriteSeq(T&& stream, size_t &bytes, std::mutex &m)
{
    std::random_device seed;
    std::mt19937 gen(seed());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
    // 1 KByte buffer.
    constexpr size_t bufSize = 1024 / sizeof(int);
    int buf[bufSize];

    while (true)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) {
            buf[i] = dist(gen);
        }

        if (bytes > 0) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m);

            if (bytes > 0) {
                stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buf), bytes > bufSize ? bufSize : bytes);
                if (bytes > bufSize) {
                    bytes -= bufSize;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } 
        return;
    }
}
```

Компиляция завершается неудачно с ошибкой: `Ошибка C2440   <function-style-cast>: невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в "std::thread"` в строке

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(GenAndWriteSeq, std::ref(stream), std::ref(byte), std::ref(mtx)));
```

Если внести некоторые изменения, то компиляция завершается успешно.

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(GenAndWriteSeq<T>, std::ref(stream), std::ref(byte), std::ref(mtx)));
```

Вызывающий код.

```
std::ofstream f("numbers.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
GenSeqByte(f, fileSize);
```

Все работает до момента, пока мы не передаем в функцию GenSeqByte rvalue.

```
GenSeqByte(std::ofstream("numbers.txt", std::ofstream::binary), fileSize);
```

Ошибка.

```
Ошибка C2672 "std::invoke": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
Ошибка C2893 Сбой при специализации функции-шаблона "unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)"
```

Comment: `GenAndWriteSeq` становится функцией только после указания аргументов шаблона, `&GenAndWriteSeq<T>`

Comment: @VTT да, если указать агрумент шаблона, то программа компилируется для lvalue объектов. Но что делать с  ``GenSeqByte(std::ofstream("numbers.txt", std::ofstream::binary), fileSize);``?

Comment: Так не надо использовать универсальную ссылку здесь. Вы же потом этот объект никуда не форвардите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае rvalue аргумента тип `T` для `GenSeqByte` дедуцируется как `Т == std::ofstream`. Тогда функция `GenAndWriteSeq<T>` будет принимать параметр типа `std::ofstream &&`. А вы передаете туда `std::ref(stream)`. `std::ref(stream)` не является корректным аргументом для `std::ofstream &&`. `std::ref` генерирует аналог lvalue-ссылки. Она не может быть использована для инициализации rvalue-ссылки.

Здесь можно было бы просто перейти на использование lvalue-ссылки внутри `GenSeqByte`, явно указав `T &` в качестве шаблонного аргумента для `GenAndWriteSeq`

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(GenAndWriteSeq<T &>, std::ref(stream), std::ref(byte), std::ref(mtx)));
```